# Dynamic SQL query writing in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, dynamic-sql

What is the best way to write a dynamic parametrized query for sql server 2005 where passed parameter value may be null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of : [`SP_EXECUTESQL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Comment: mine is not stored procedure it's a parametrized query

Comment: GO TO LINK AND SEE THE DOUCMENT ITS ALL TALK ABOUT EXCUETING DYNAMIC PARAMETERIZE QUERY

Comment: @abatishchev - ok actually my caps is on that time

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        val1 VARCHAR(20),
        val2 VARCHAR(20)
)

DECLARE @Param VARCHAR(20)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '1','2'
SELECT  *
FROM    @Table
WHERE   (@Param IS NULL OR val1 = @Param)
```

However, this will slow down performance. **I would recomend that when you build your dynamic query, dont add parameters to the where clause, if it is not requied.**

Answer (score 1):

Only if possible:
Write the query with all the parameters included, but instead of writing a regular

```
WHERE
    field1=@param1
    and field2=@param2
    .....
```

write

```
WHERE
    (@param1 is null or field1=@param1)
    and (@param2 is null or field2=@param2)
    ...
```

or

```
WHERE
    field1=isnull(@param1,field1)
    and field2=isnull(@param2,field2)
    ...
```

but if serious performance issues occur, consider writing the query for each single case.
ONLY if this query executes many many times per second on small tables, there is a reason to write it entirely, use sp_prepare/sp_execute for it, so it will run fastest in this case.

Comment: first let me know how do you format the code written in comment so that i can send you my code in formatted form

Comment: there is a JS running on this site, that formats it automatically. Just prepend each row with at least 4 spaces when writing the QUESTION or ANSWER (Doesn't work for comments). Or you could use the tool panel of the WYSIWYG editor on this site. The spaces/tabs I've added manually, because the site doesn't manage those.

Comment: what else can i do to retain performance
i want to know some code as you did above please let me know?

Comment: It all depends on the situation. This is a too broad question. You could try to search here for answers, or ask yourself a question about performance. But to know it better, the only way is to study, search the internet, or hire a consultant or teacher.